# Running out of memory, or running out of disk space?

Tags: postgresql, memory-usage, disk-space-utilization, virtual-memory

I'm running a database loading process (osm2pgsql) which is failing:

```
Processing: Node(17404k 148.8k/s) Way(1351k 6.38k/s) Relation(9520 29.94/s)way_done failed: ERROR:  could not extend file "base/140667/152463": No space left on device
HINT:  Check free disk space.
(7)
Arguments were: 187226311,
```

At the start of the import, `mem` reports:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           31G        29G       2.4G         0B       178M        24G
-/+ buffers/cache:       4.5G        26G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

Shortly before the end:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           31G        31G       227M         0B       178M        26G
-/+ buffers/cache:       4.8G        26G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

Meanwhile, `df` at the start:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       10309828   7879412   1997036  80% /
udev            16470572        12  16470560   1% /dev
tmpfs            6590080       260   6589820   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none            16475196         0  16475196   0% /run/shm
none              102400         0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/vdb       247709760 105978300 129148548  46% /mnt
```

And from about 3/4 of the way through the process. Use sits at 100%.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       10309828   9854348     22100 100% /
udev            16470572        12  16470560   1% /dev
tmpfs            6590080       260   6589820   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none            16475196         0  16475196   0% /run/shm
none              102400         0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/vdb       247709760 105978300 129148548  46% /mnt
```

I'm unable to identify any actual files on disk that are filling up /dev/vda1:

```
du -h -d 3 / 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^0 > /tmp/o2p1.txt
[start import]
du -h -d 3 / 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^0 > /tmp/o2p2.txt

diff /tmp/o2p1.txt /tmp/o2p2.txt
```

That reveals nothing.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it was simple. The Postgres database was on /dev/vda1 and was getting huge. It didn't show up in the `du` command because I wasn't running that as root.

I guess after the disk fills up, Postgres stops saving to disk and keeps it all in memory - until memory runs out as well.